# django admin - how to get the current url parameters in python

Tags: django, django-admin

Here I made an example of what I have in my admin.py:

```
@admin.register(Car)
class CarAdmin(CustomAdmin):
    list_display = ('get_color',)
    def get_color(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('<a href="/admin/myapp/car/?color={}">{}</a>'.format(obj.color, obj.color))
```

I have produced a link that can be used to display cars with a specific color.
Let's say the page is currently showing cars that cost less than $20k and I want this link to preserve the current filter.
Any ideas how to do that? Maybe there is a way to get the current url from python.

Note that I know I can write a javascript to modify the links after the page is loaded, but that is a terrible solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can save the full path or request before the get_color is called, something like:

```
class CarAdmin(CustomAdmin):
    list_display = ('get_color',)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        self.full_path = request.get_full_path()
        return super().get_queryset(request)

    def get_color(self, obj):
        # TODO: Handle empty query parameters 
        return mark_safe(f'<a href="{self.full_path}&color={obj.color}">{obj.color}</a>')
```